# Not receiving messages from Kafka Topic

Tags: python, apache-kafka, python-multithreading, threadpoolexecutor, confluent-kafka-python

I am receiving None when calling poll() in this program but I am getting the messages when running the kafka-console-consumer.bat from cmd, I can't figure out what exactly the problem.

The execution starts from main.py

```
from queue import Queue
from concurrent.futures import ThreadPoolExecutor
import time
import json
from kafka_message_consumer import KafkaMessageConsumer
from kafka_discovery_executor import KafkaDiscoveryExecutor


with open('kafka_properties.json') as f:
    kafka_properties = json.loads(f.read())

message_queue = Queue()
kafka_message_consumer = KafkaMessageConsumer(kafka_properties, message_queue)
kafka_discovery_executor = KafkaDiscoveryExecutor(message_queue, kafka_properties)

with ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=5) as executor:
    executor.submit(kafka_message_consumer.run())
    time.sleep(1)
    executor.submit(kafka_discovery_executor.run())
    time.sleep(1)
```

KafkaDiscoveryExecutor class is for consuming messages from shared queue and processing that messages.

This is kafka_message_consumer.py

```
import logging
from confluent_kafka import Consumer


class KafkaMessageConsumer:

    def __init__(self, kafka_properties, message_queue):
        self.message_queue = message_queue
        self.logger = logging.getLogger('KafkaMessageConsumer')
        self.kafka_stream_consumer = None
        self.create_consumer(kafka_properties)

    def create_consumer(self, kafka_properties):
        """
        Create an instance of Kafka Consumer with the consumer configuration properties
        and subscribes to the defined topic(s).
        """

        consumer_config = dict()

        # Consumer configuration properties.
        consumer_config['bootstrap.servers'] = kafka_properties.get('bootstrap.servers')
        consumer_config['group.id'] = kafka_properties.get('group.id')
        consumer_config['enable.auto.commit'] = True
        consumer_config['auto.offset.reset'] = 'earliest'
        
        # For SSL Security
        # consumer_config['security.protocol'] = 'SASL_SSL'
        # consumer_config['sasl.mechanisms'] = 'PLAIN'
        # consumer_config['sasl.username'] = ''
        # consumer_config['sasl.password'] = ''

        # Create the consumer using consumer_config.
        self.kafka_stream_consumer = Consumer(consumer_config)

        # Subscribe to the specified topic(s).
        self.kafka_stream_consumer.subscribe(['mytopic'])

    def run(self):
        while True:
            msg = self.kafka_stream_consumer.poll(1.0)
            if msg is None:
                # No message available within timeout.
                print("Waiting for message or event/error in poll()")
                continue
            elif msg.error():
                print("Error: {}".format(msg.error()))
            else:
            # Consume the record.
            # Push the message into message_queue
                try:
                    self.message_queue.put(msg)
                except Exception as e:
                    self.logger.critical("Error occured in kafka Consumer: {}".format(e))
```

The specified topic has events but I am getting None here and the print statement inside 'if msg is None:' is executing.

Comment: Without looking at the detail (I'm not a python developer) two most likely causes (or the only possible causes really AFAIK) are (1) there is another consumer with the same group name that consumes the message - that could be any consumer including your console consumer or (2) your application is using a new group name (or a group that has never committed) and your configuration is to start from latest when no committed offsets exist, and the message is published before your first poll

Comment: I have tried with different group id too and also running the producer before running the consumer but still getting None.

Comment: How do you know you are not consuming the messages - where is the message queue that you are forwarding them to? In your code you are (correctly) polling continuously but that means you will keep logging as long as there is nothing new, and you don't log anything if you do get a message but just put it on some other queue - I'm not familiar with the queue library, also not sure what Kafka discovery executor is, but are you sure nothing goes to that message queue?

Comment: (ps I see you have auto.offset.reset as earliest so there should be no issue with whether the messages are published before or after a new consumer group starts consuming - we can rule that out as a cause.

Comment: Just to check I created a separate consumer to see if I am receiving message and yeah it's working but still not sure why this program is not working

Comment: KafkaDiscoveryExecutor class is for consuming the messages from the queue and some processing stuff.

Comment: How about stripping this back to something a tiny bit simpler - take away the push to another queue, just have a consumer that logs when poll returns nothing and logs something else when it returns something

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/238479/discussion-between-paniclion-and-chris).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### I am still not sure as to why the above code is not working as it should.

Here's what changes I made to make this code work

1. I used threading module instead of concurrent.futures
2. used daemon thread
3. make a call to thread.**init**() inside the constructor of the classes [KafkaMessageConsumer, KafkaDiscoveryExecutor]

**Here's main.py**

```
from queue import Queue
import threading
import time
import json
from kafka_message_consumer import KafkaMessageConsumer
from kafka_discovery_executor import KafkaDiscoveryExecutor

def main():
    with open('kafka_properties.json') as f:
        kafka_properties = json.loads(f.read())

    message_queue = Queue()
   
    threads = [
        KafkaMessageConsumer(kafka_properties, message_queue),
        KafkaDiscoveryExecutor(message_queue, kafka_properties)
    ]

    for thread in threads:
        thread.start()
        time.sleep(1)

    for thread in threads:
        thread.join()

    time.sleep(1)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

**and kafka_message_consumer.py**

```
import logging
from confluent_kafka import Consumer
import threading


class KafkaMessageConsumer(threading.Thread):
    daemon = True

    def __init__(self, kafka_properties, message_queue):
        threading.Thread.__init__(self)
        self.message_queue = message_queue
        self.logger = logging.getLogger('KafkaMessageConsumer')
        self.kafka_stream_consumer = None
        self.create_consumer(kafka_properties)

    def create_consumer(self, kafka_properties):
        """
        Create an instance of Kafka Consumer with the consumer configuration properties
        and subscribes to the defined topic(s).
        """

        consumer_config = dict()

        # Consumer configuration properties.
        consumer_config['bootstrap.servers'] = kafka_properties.get('bootstrap.servers')
        consumer_config['group.id'] = kafka_properties.get('group.id')
        consumer_config['enable.auto.commit'] = True
        consumer_config['auto.offset.reset'] = 'earliest'
        

        # Create the consumer using consumer_config.
        self.kafka_stream_consumer = Consumer(consumer_config)

        # Subscribe to the specified topic(s).
        self.kafka_stream_consumer.subscribe(['mytopic'])

    def run(self):
        while True:
            msg = self.kafka_stream_consumer.poll(1.0)
            if msg is None:
                # No message available within timeout.
                print("Waiting for message or event/error in poll()")
                continue
            elif msg.error():
                print("Error: {}".format(msg.error()))
            else:
            # Consume the record.
            # Push the message into message_queue
                try:
                    self.message_queue.put(msg)
                except Exception as e:
                    self.logger.critical("Error occured in kafka Consumer: {}".format(e))
        self.kafka_stream_consumer.close()
```